# what does colon wrapped class mean in python comment?

Tags: python, class, pytorch

What does colon wrapped class (`:class:`) mean in python comment?

For example,

```
class Optimizer(object):
    r"""Base class for all optimizers.
    Arguments:
        params (iterable): an iterable of :class:`torch.Tensor` s or
            :class:`dict` s. Specifies what Tensors should be optimized.
        defaults: (dict): a dict containing default values of optimization
            options (used when a parameter group doesn't specify them).
    """

    def __init__(self, params, defaults):
        self.defaults = defaults
```

Is it a pytorch-specific syntax, or what?

Source: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/optimizer.py

Comment: I'd wager just how the documentation tool parses to build pages

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#writing-documentation → https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's nothing Python or Torch specific. It's syntax for a documentation tool; most likely [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/).

The syntax indicates a cross-reference to the documentation for another class. When the documentation tool generates hyperlinked output such as HTML, such references automatically become links to the documentation page for the named class.

For Sphinx, see the [*Cross-referencing syntax* documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#cross-referencing-syntax); there you'd see `py:class:` as a class-reference, but we can assume the default domain is set to Python so `:class:` is valid too.

The PyTorch project indeed [uses Sphinx to generate the documenation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0f65c9267d5ec55584b0ec65acb5374c95af9c16/docs/make.bat). You can compare the source you found with[the resulting generated documenation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer); note how both `dict` and `torch.Tensor` are hyperlinks to more documentation.